# How to include the "Configuration" panel of report as in the doc example?

Tags: report, config, snakemake

Using snakemake version 5.18.1, how can we have the "Configuration" panel, as in in the example given here: https://koesterlab.github.io/resources/report.html?

I have looked around in the Doc and on github, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Thank you for the great work and best regards,

Valentin

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be generated automatically if you write the following in the Snakefile.
I usually put the config.yml in the same directory as the Snakefile

```
configfile: "config.yaml"
```

Thanks,